# Cylindrical Shells $x=4 y^2$

Tags: calculus

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume V generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
$x = 4 y^2$, $y ≥ 0$, $x = 4$;  about $y = 2$.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about cylindrical shells? What ideas do you have? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am unsure of where to start it off

Comment: For what reason? Because you don't know what the shell method is? What makes this problem hard, or interesting?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: sketch the region you are integrating.

step 2: find the limits of integration.

step 3: what is the volume of each shell?

step 4: integrate.

Which of these steps is troubling you?  Which of these have you successfully completed?

Comment: I think that requests for further clarification are better left as comments.

Comment: +1 for not spoiling it though